# Optimize delete query generated by Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: castle-activerecord

Lets say I have `Id` (primary key) list that I want to delete (e.g 1, 2, 3, 4).
Using this query :

```
Console.WriteLine ("DELETE DATA :");
ActiveRecordMediator<PostgrePerson>.DeleteAll ("Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)");
```

I expect the console output is :

```
DELETE DATA :
NHibernate: DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**but**, the actual console output is (I use showsql option) :

```
DELETE DATA :
NHibernate: select postgreper0_.Id as Id5_, postgreper0_.Name as Name5_, postgreper0_.Age as Age5_, postgreper0_.Address as Address5_ from Person postgreper0_ w
here postgreper0_.Id in (1 , 2 , 3 , 4)
NHibernate: DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id = :p0;:p0 = 1
NHibernate: DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id = :p0;:p0 = 2
NHibernate: DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id = :p0;:p0 = 3
NHibernate: DELETE FROM Person WHERE Id = :p0;:p0 = 4
```

What should I do to make Castle ActiveRecord generate the expected (optimized) query?

**Update** 
This is my implementation based on accepted answer.

```
int[] idList = GetIdList ();
ActiveRecordMediator<PostgrePerson>.Execute ((session, obj) => {
    string hql = "DELETE PostgrePerson WHERE Id IN (:idList)";
    return session.CreateQuery (hql)
        .SetParameterList ("idList", idList)
        .ExecuteUpdate ();
}, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Execute callback](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/hql.html#ExecCallback) method and run a [DML-style HQL DELETE](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct) on the NHibernate ISession.

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected :) It's seem that current version of activerecord doesn't yet support using DML-style HQL statement directly from `HqlBasedQuery`